# Camel CXF not decrypting SOAP Response

Tags: cxf, jbossfuse

We're invoking a secured SOAP WebService using Camel CXF deployed in Fuse. In the client, we have configured TrustStore and Keystore as per the standard config. We're able to hit the server via Netscaler. The server is generating the response and sending it back to Netscaler.

When the response is received from Netscaler, it is encrypted and should be decrypted by Camel CXF. The decryption is not happening and on the client we get a parsing error since the response is all encrypted.

Any clues of what could be the problem ?

The only stackTrace that I see is that the message failed to parse because of the presence of Ctrl characters since the message is encrypted.

```
<http:conduit name="https.*">
    <http:tlsClientParameters secureSocketProtocol="TLS">
        <sec:keyManagers ref="keyManagersBean"/>
        <sec:trustManagers ref="trustManagersBean"/>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
</http:conduit>
```

The keyManager and trustManager beans are created using a custom factory.

Also, could this issue be because apart from transport level encryption, we also need message level encryption ?

Comment: So no stacktraces or errors from cxf? Could you provide your ws client configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved. The issue was the the content was gzipped before being sent from NetScaler. Hence, after transport level decryption we could still see the headers but not the content. Adding a GZip in & fault interceptor on the CXF endpoint fixed the issue.